# QGIS: Connect to a REST service

Tags: qgis, arcgis-rest-api

I want to connect to this REST Service, from QGIS Essen, using its URI:

http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Property/MapServer/2?f=pjson

Any tips please?

I tried adding it as a Vector layer, protocal GeoJSON. I also tried the OGR method, constructed as follows; ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON NSW_Property_20160314.json "maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Property/…*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  What are the "tricks" that you have already tried?  Telling us this at the outset saves potential answerers having to guess and waste their volunteered time that could be spent trying new "tricks".

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks, I tried adding it as a Vector layer, protocal GeoJSON. I also tried the OGR method, constructed as follows;

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON NSW_Property_20160314.json "http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Property/MapServer/query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that is there for you to use to revise your question with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Layer -> Add Layer -> Add ArcGIS FeatureServer

Copy only this in the URL
http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Property/MapServer
Put a name and thats all.

Or in navigator: right click on ArcGisFeatureServer -> New connection

[image]

[image]

Copy the url, put a name and click in ok. And you get this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you read [This](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Arcgis_rest) you will see that it is not possible to import ArcGIS Server REST as vector layers.

My advice would be to use the WMS that is available (see below). Also if you select the image type as PNG then you will just get the boundaries of the polygons and the rest will be transparent.

http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/public/NSW_Property/MapServer/WMSServer?

Comment: thanks, I did try those approaches but they didn't work (see my edits above).

I do have the images rendering from the WMS service as you describe, as rasters, but not the "polygons" in vector format.