# Add imagery from SIX maps using WMS

Tags: wms

I am new to QGIS WMS and trying to add imagery from [Six Maps](https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/).

https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Imagery/MapServer

I have tried the steps in here also adding as an ArcGisFeatureServer -> New connection [QGIS: Connect to a REST service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184762/qgis-connect-to-a-rest-service) however this didn't work either.

I get the error message

```
Failed to retrieve service capabilities:
Parsing error: illegal value
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken what you are wanting to be doing is called consuming (not serving) that WMS.

Answer (score 6):

That's not a WMS or ArcGisFeatureServer URL, it's an ArcGIS MapServer URL.

To connect, in the browser panel, right click on ArcGISMapServer and select "New Connection...". Enter a name, i.e Six Maps and paste in your URL.

[image]