# ArcMap Open Carto 2 WMTS not displaying in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-rest-api, wmts

I am a little perplexed as to why I cannot get the OS Open Carto 2 Basemap from Arcmap's Rest Services to display in QGIS.

The WMTS link is here *([OS Open Carto 2](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?cacheKey=ab093530753e4ad5)) but upon adding it to QGIS through the "Create a New WMS/WMTS Connection" window it is accepted but no map is displayed. The WMTS for Carto does not appear to be down on the Arcmap web map either ([see here](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer?view=wmtsview&cacheKey=ab093530753e4ad5))

**Connection String (OS Open Carto 2)**

> https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?cacheKey=ab093530753e4ad5

[image]

**Connection String (OS Open Raster)**

In contrast when I add the OS Open Raster WMTS all works fine.

> https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Raster/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?cacheKey=b499350066619da6

Comment: The carto service is advertising http URLs in the GetCapabilities response, but there doesn't appear to be an HTTP service, only HTTPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. I was able to reproduce the problem, which gave the following output in the `wms` tab of the logger:

```
2020-12-09T15:15:33     WARNING    Tile request error (Status: 200; Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8; Length: 1580; URL: http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OS_Open_Carto_2/default/default028mm/8/28/38.png)
2020-12-09T15:15:33     WARNING    Tile request error (Status: 200; Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8; Length: 1580; URL: http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OS_Open_Carto_2/default/default028mm/8/29/38.png)
2020-12-09T15:15:33     WARNING    Tile request error (Status: 200; Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8; Length: 1580; URL: http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OS_Open_Carto_2/default/default028mm/8/30/38.png)
2020-12-09T15:15:33     WARNING    Tile request error (Status: 200; Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8; Length: 1580; URL: http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OS_Open_Carto_2/default/default028mm/8/30/42.png)
2020-12-09T15:15:33     WARNING    Tile request error (Status: 200; Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8; Length: 1580; URL: http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OS_Open_Carto_2/default/default028mm/8/29/40.png)
```

However, any of the [urls](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OS_Open_Carto_2/default/default028mm/12/694/934.png) link to a valid png image on the web.

Luckily, there are multiple ways of displaying ArcGIS rest maps in QGIS:

**1. as a WMTS**

this is what we tried.

**2. As an ArcGIS MapService** [(thread)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184762/qgis-connect-to-a-rest-service)

this worked.

1. `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add ArcGIS Map Service Layer`...
2. click `new`
3. Give a descriptive name and paste the URL. It should end on `/MapServer` so: https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer
4. `OK` -> `Add`
5. done

**3. As described in [this wiki](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/wiki/Arcgis_rest).**

Using this method, you Should be able to get vector layers from Rest API as well.
I could not get it working with the Open Carto Map (and have not tried it with others).

Comment: Were you able to get the layer working in QGIS?

Comment: yes, using method 2.

Comment: were you able to actually visualize the data from Open Carto using method 2? If I follow the steps it gives a blank layer...

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is not possible to use that specific service as a native WMTS one, but a workaround is to use it as a `XYZ` tile service:

you will need to set this URL in the XYZ dialog:

[https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OS_Open_Carto_2/default/default028mm/{z}/{y}/{x}.png](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/OS_Open_Carto_2/default/default028mm/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.png)

please note that the CRS needs to be fixed (as `EPSG:27700`)

As a reference, this URL from the same server works as a native WMTS layer:

https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ULBqC49IEeIR01GF/arcgis/rest/services/Middle_East_Oil_and_Gas_Field_Map_by_CIA/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml?cacheKey=aec62228d3e2389d

[image]